# Downloading data from yahoo finance with a dash or dot in the ticker

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have this code to download data from yahoo:

```
#gets data from yahoo finance
stocks = list(newmerge.index)
start = dt.datetime(2012,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.today()

yahoodata = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks,start,end)
cleanData = yahoodata.loc['Adj Close']
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(cleanData, columns=stocks)
```

It works fine but I noticed a problem recently, it doesn't download data for stocks "BRK.B" , and "BR.B" .

I have a list of all the stocks called "stocks" , and here's what I've done, but it still doesn't show data for stocks w/ dot in them:

```
def stocksdot(stocks):
stocks_dash = str(stocks).replace('.','-')
stockslist = stocks_dash.split(',')
return stockslist

stocksdot(stocks)
```

My expected output would be to download all stocks, even those with a dot in them. Any ideas how to circumvent?

Comment: Please provide a fully working [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to make helping you easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is Yahoo Finance doesn't use the "." notation to track shares of different classes. So, "BRK.B" and "BR.B" are actually "BRKB" and "BRB".

Using the Yahoo Finance python [SDK](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.1.4) I made a little script to test whether or not Yahoo Finance could find information about a stock with the ticker "BRK.B" or "BR.B".

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

stock = Share('BRK.B')
print(stock.get_price())
```

This results is:

```
>>>> None
```

Stock tickers with a dot in them are used as a shorthand for a type or class of a specific stock. You can learn more [here](http://finance.zacks.com/dot-ticker-symbol-mean-11643.html).

To circumvent it looks like you can remove the ".". For example when I use "BRKB" instead of "BRK.B" I get the result:

```
>>>> 173.05
```

Which is the current price of Berkshire Hathaway class B stock.

To replace the "." programatically use Python's .replace() method.

```
for stock in stocks:
    stock = stock.replace(".", "")  # Replaces all "." with "" in the string 
                                # stock
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work, but my stocks are in a list, and it says replace cant be used on list

Comment: Please see my edit. You just need to loop over every stock in the list and call replace on the individual stock. Please upvote and mark as accepted if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is Yahoo Finance doesn't use the "." notation to track shares of different classes. So, "BRK.B" and "BR.B" are actually "BRKB" and "BRB". --- My comment: Now "BRK.B" and "BR.B" are actually "BRK-B" and "BR-B".